# Read CSV files with both Double and Single quote variables

Tags: ruby, csv, bigdata

I am working with very large files (e.g. 1GB+) and want to read in a string variable from a csv that potentially has a single or a double quote within the variable.

Is there a way to do this quickly an efficiently upon opening the CSV? Or is the most efficient way to use the quote_char variable for one type of quote and escape the other type of quote in the string?

```
CSV.foreach('file.csv', :quote_char=>"'", :force_quotes => false) do |row|
     string_value = row[0]
end
```

Comment: Can you please add a short CSV example that illustrates your problem and the expected output?

Comment: 1,243242,hello "world"

Comment: The provided example does not contain fields with _both_ single and double quotes. Please carefully provide the correct example.

Comment: The above code can handle single quotes but not double, but ok, here is another example:
1,243242,hello "world"
1,243242,hey ‘there’
2,34343,bye bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trick: just provide a `quote_char` parameter with *definitely inexisting in the input symbol*:

```
CSV.new(%|"foo'bar",'foo"bar','foo bar',"foo bar"|, quote_char: ?*).read
#⇒ [["\"foo'bar\"", "'foo\"bar'", "'foo bar'", "\"foo bar\""]]
```